# What is the logical idea of self orthogonality?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, orthogonality

I know how to calculate the orthogonal trajectory of a given family of curves. And it is said in my text book that if the orthogonal trajectory of a curve is itself, then we say that the family of curves is self orthogonal. As an example, orthogonal trajectory of parabola $$y^2=4a\left(x+a\right)$$  Is the same function. But how this is possible? Orhogonal trajectory cut every member of given family normally. I cannot get an idea of self orthogonality. I tried to graph the above equation with suitable $a$ . But I cannot agree with the fact that the same function is its orthogonal trajectory. I try an algebraic approach. If $m$ is the slope of such function at a point $x$ , then $\frac{-1}{m}$ is also its slope at $x$ . This gives, $$m^2=-1\\  
\implies {m=i}$$
thus, the slope I get is a complex value for such functions. But I cannot agree with it. Where is my mistake? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if $m$ is the slope of a function in the given family, than $\frac{-1}{m}$ is the slope, at the same $x$, of **another** function of the same family ( this is your mistake, I suppose).

See the figure:

[image]

where this is illustrated for the values $a=1$ and $a=-1$ for the functions of your family ( the semiplane $y<0$ is symmetric). The two functions are:
$$
a=1 \rightarrow y^2=4(x+1)  \rightarrow y=2\sqrt{x+1}
$$
$$
a=-1 \rightarrow y^2=4(1-x)  \rightarrow y=2\sqrt{1-x}
$$
that have orthogonal tangents at $x=0$.

For an analitic approach:

you can see that $m=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a(x+a)}}$ so the condition of othogonality for two curves of the family with parameters $a$ and $b$ is:
$$
\frac{a}{\sqrt{a(x+a)}}=-\frac{\sqrt{b(x+b)}}{b}
$$
squaring, with the condition $ab<0$, this becomes:
$$
x^2+(a+b)x=0
$$
and this means that if the two curves have a common point at $x=0$, at this point they are orthogonal, or they can be orthogonal at $x=-(a+b)$.

Comment: Will you provide a more specific graph showing how the parabola can be self-orthogonal geometrically?

Comment: What do you means by ''more specific''? The graph in the answer show tho parabolas that are orthogonal at the intersection point.

Comment: If the parabola is self orthogonal, how is there supposed to be another graph which is orthogonal to it?